# {OpenAL(+FFmpeg)} How to queue variable size buffer due to ogg format?

Tags: ffmpeg, openal

(First of all, I may feel sorry about my poor English as it's not my native language.)

I use FFmpeg to decode some audio file and play it with OpenAL by "stream"(i.e."queue" and "unqueue" function of OpenAL).

When I use my program to play .ogg file, I find that it has a variable nb_samples.(due to ogg has variable bit rate??) There are 128 B, 512 B and 1024 B of nb_samples. As a results, I must call alDeleteBuffers and alGenBuffers before I use alBufferSamplesSOFT(similar to alBufferData) because it would fail to call alBufferSamplesSOFT without recreate the buffer.
Notes: alBufferSamplesSOFT is provided by OpenAL Soft. You can just see it as alBufferData.

Nevertheless, I think it's foolish and inefficient if I do this. Is there is some smart method? I paste the part of code:

```
while (av_read_frame(...) == 0){
  avcodec_decode_audio4(...);
  swr_convert(...);  // to convert PCM format from FLTP to FLT
  alDeleteBuffers(1, theBuffers[?]);
  alGenBuffers(1, theBuffers[?]);
  alBufferSamplesSOFT(...);  // put those data into OpenAL buffer
}
```

if I don't do this, It would failed to update the OpenAL buffer. Is there any method to create a variable size buffer or a big size buffer? Or is there any method to change the size of buffer?

Thanks for you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on the FIFO functionality of libavresample (supported by FFmpeg), such as:

```
... decode the audio into srcaudio frame...
// Resample the input into the audioSampleBuffer until we proceed the whole decoded data
if ( (err = avresample_convert( audioResampleCtx,
                                NULL,
                                0,
                                0,
                                srcaudio.data,
                                0,
                                srcaudio.nb_samples )) < 0 )
{
    warning( "Error resampling decoded audio: %d", err );
    return -1;
}

while( avresample_available( audioResampleCtx ) >= audioFrame->nb_samples )
{
    // Read a frame audio data from the resample fifo
    if ( avresample_read( audioResampleCtx, audioFrame->data, audioFrame->nb_samples ) != audioFrame->nb_samples )
    {
        warning( "Error reading resampled audio: %d", err );
        return -1;
    }
```

This way you will always get back the fixed size buffer via `avresample_read`. It also has the benefit if you're converting audio in a way which generates more samples from the source file than nb_samples.

The code piece is from my Karaoke Lyrics Editor; you can check the respective source file [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/karlyriceditor/code/HEAD/tree/src/ffmpegvideoencoder.cpp) if you need more information.